# COMBINING TWO QUERIES INTO SINGLE QUERY IN VIEW

Tags: sql, view, sql-server-2014

I have this view which contains a `union all` query and returns the results shown below:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MANU_TEST] 
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT
        PT.PRODUCT AS PRODUCT, PT.TEXT_CODE AS TEXT_CODE, 
        PHT.PHRASE AS F_PHRASE,PHT.LANGUAGE 
    FROM 
        PRODUCT_TEXT PT
    LEFT JOIN 
        PHRASE_LINK PHL ON PT.TEXT_CODE = PHL.TEXT_CODE
    INNER JOIN 
        PHRASE_TRANSLATIONS PHT ON PHL.PHRASE_ID = PHT.PHRASE_ID
    WHERE 
        PT.DATA_CODE = 'MANU' AND PHT.LANGUAGE = 'EN'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT
        PT.F_ALIAS AS PRODUCT, PT.TEXT_CODE AS TEXT_CODE, 
        PHT.PHRASE AS F_PHRASE,PHT.LANGUAGE  
    FROM 
        PROD_ALIAS_TEXT PT
    LEFT JOIN 
        PHRASE_LINK PHL ON PT.TEXT_CODE = PHL.TEXT_CODE
    INNER JOIN 
        PHRASE_TRANSLATIONS PHT ON PHL.PHRASE_ID = PHT.PHRASE_ID
    WHERE 
        PT.DATA_CODE = 'MANU' AND PHT.LANGUAGE = 'EN'
```

Output:

```
F_PRODUCT       F_TEXTCODE       F_PHRASE F_LANGUAGE
-----------------------------------------------------
A               MANU001          TEST1     EN
A               MANU002          TEST2     EN
```

I created another view from above view using stuff to display below output.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MANU_STUFFED] 
AS
    SELECT 
        V1.F_PRODUCT, v1.F_LANGUAGE,
        F_TEXT_CODES = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + V2.F_TEXT_CODE 
                              FROM MANU_TEST V2 
                              WHERE V1.F_PRODUCT = V2.F_PRODUCT        
                              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''),
        F_PHRASES = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ' |par ' + V3.F_PHRASE 
                           FROM MANU_TEST V3 
                           WHERE V1.F_PRODUCT = V3.F_PRODUCT
                           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 5, '') 
    FROM 
        MANU_TEST V1 
    GROUP BY 
        V1.F_PRODUCT, V1.F_LANGUAGE
```

Output:

```
F_PRODUCT  F_LANGUAGE  F_TEXTCODES,          F_PHRASES
-------------------------------------------------------------
A           EN         MANU001,MANU002      TEST1 |par TEST2
```

It is working, but is it possible to combine the above two queries into one query in a single view?

Answer (score 1):

Of course.  You can use CTEs in views:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MANU_STUFFED] AS
    WITH MANU_TEST AS (
          SELECT . . . 
    )
    SELECT . . .;
```

The `. . .` are your existing queries.

Comment: yes i used CTE in views.It is working.but it takes 4 sec display four thousand records.CTE will impact performance?

Comment: @Ram . . . Compared to what?  A CTE is the same as a subquery.